# Setting navigationItem title delay issues

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

When pushing a controller to the navigation stack i execute:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "";
```

As i dont want the next view to show the name of the previous controller on the back button.

When i get back to that controller i do this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationItem.title = "Title Of View";
    ...
}
```

The title is set appropriately but it lags for about 1 second or so.. I remember using this techinique for quite some time without having a problem in the past. The code that sets the titles isn't within a network call or anything like that..

Any ideas about what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to hide the back button title you should set empty `UIBarButtonItem` instance to the `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`
right after you push the new view controller, like so:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .done, target: nil, action: nil)
```

This way you don't have to manipulate the title of the view controller.

Comment: Here's an oddity. Assume controller A and controller B. Adding your code for controller B does nothing. Adding your code for controller A and then pushing controller B does the trick. This is quite confusing to me, why do i need to change the UIBarButtonItem on the previous controller and the current one?

Comment: Here is the thing, controller A's `backBarButtonItem` is displayed on Controller B. You should not think about `backBarButtonItem` is displayed on it's `navigationItem`'s controller, think about it like it takes you to that controller.

Comment: I see, surprisingly this makes sense. Sorry for my limited understanding of it and thanks : D